# using yield to return an array of data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, rest, yield

I never used generators in PHP. I understand the way to use it :
Foreach an array to do some tasks for each value like greping a specific line into a big file to remove some caracteres..

What I need :

I need to retrieve all bands from my dabatase. Sure I have the 'limit' argument to don't exceed the PHP's memory (there're 30 000 bands..).
I have to filters values and return a new array to the client into my REST API.

What I want to know :

Is it interesting for me to create a method into a trait called 'generator' to perform the code bellow ?

In all cases, I have to create a new array to return it into my method

```
    $bands = Models\Bands::find($bandsParameters);
    $json  = [];

    foreach ($bands as $band) {
        $followers    = $band->getFollowers();
        $followersArr = [];

        foreach ($followers as $follower) {
            $followerImage = $follower->getImage();
            $followerObj   = (object)[
                'id'        => $follower->id,
                'username'  => $follower->username,
                'image'     => $followerImage->url,
                'online'    => $follower->online,
                'createdOn' => $follower->createdOn,
                'updatedOn' => $follower->updatedOn,
                'lastLogin' => $follower->lastLogin,
            ];
            $followersArr[] = $followerObj;
        }

        $info    = $band->getInfo($bandInfoParameters)->getFirst();
        $bandObj = (object)[
            'id'         => $band->id,
            'name'       => $band->name,
            'style'      => $band->styles,
            'country'    => $band->country,
            'summary'    => isset($info->summary) ? $info->summary : null,
            'followers'  => $followersArr,
            'createdOn'  => $band->createdOn,
            'updatedOn'  => $band->updatedOn,
            'authoredBy' => $band->authoredBy,
            'updatedBy'  => $band->updatedBy,
        ];

        $json[] = $bandObj;
    }

    return ['key' => 'bands', 'value' => $json];
```

Comment: You can create a new function that does it cleanly

Comment: Is this a answer for my question about using generators ..? I know I can factorise my code but I want to know if using generator could be interesting for me if I need to return an array containing my data